# link page to other global navigation site

Tags: sharepoint-server, navigation

I just want to link "Travel" page under "Customers" navigation on the global navigation. I tried using look and feel(Navigation), but I couldn't see under "Customers" site on the global navigation with same site collection.

[image]

Comment: Please, add some precision. Like location of page "Travel" on the hierarchy and what you thought should be seen on the global navigation (or the editing dialogs of global navigation?).

Comment: "Travel" Page created from "Transport" sub site, But I want to link the page under Customers. Cos user simply to get on the home page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question. Is "Travel" a page or a subsite of Customers? Are you trying to display it on the global navigation of Customers or of some other site collection?

If you want it displayed on the Customers site you need to make sure that Customers global navigation settings has "Show pages" and/or "Show subsites" selected.

If you want to display it on a different site collection you may have to manually add it as a link.

Martin

Comment: Thanks Martin for prompt respond. "Travel" is  a page , so that We want to put this page under global navigation called "Customers"

Comment: Manually add the link to the URL in the navigation settings for the Customer sub site. From the Customer sub site go into Site Settings, the Navigation. Scroll down and click on Add Link.